# Type error when composing any function with the vector `create` function

Tags: haskell

The following code will be not compile:

```
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as V
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable as MV

bad :: V.Vector Int
bad = id . V.create $ do
    v <- MV.new 1
    MV.set v 0
    pure v
```

> ```
> • Couldn't match type ‘m0 (MV.MVector
>                              (Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState m0) a0)’
>                  with ‘forall s. GHC.ST.ST s (MV.MVector s Int)’
>   Expected type: m0 (MV.MVector
>                        (Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState m0) a0)
>                  -> V.Vector Int
>     Actual type: (forall s. GHC.ST.ST s (MV.MVector s Int))
>                  -> V.Vector Int
> • In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘V.create’
>   In the expression: id . V.create
>   In the expression:
>     id . V.create
>     $ do { v <- MV.new 1;
>            MV.set v 0;
>            pure v }
> ```

But next will be:

```
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as V
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable as MV
```

```
good :: V.Vector Int
good = id $ V.create $ do
    v <- MV.new 1
    MV.set v 0
    pure v
```

`stack` resolver is lts-9.12

So, why it does and how to fix if I prefer to compose by `(.)`?

Comment: What function do you actually want to use instead of `id`? (`id . f == f`) The problem here, I think, is that `V.create` is existentially qualified, but `id` is not.

Comment: As instance, `Data.Array.Repa.fromUnboxed someShape`.

Comment: I think you might be able to "fix" this with a preprocessing step that replaces saturated applications of `(.)` with the appropriate lambdas. That is, you'd manually inline `(.)` before running the type checker. But you might have to do some extra work to shift lambdas to the left of the `=` or (case) `->`, so it may not be so trivial.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've hit the fact that GHC can't do impredicative polymorphism. `V.create` has the higher rank type `forall a. Unbox a => (forall s. ST s (MVector s a)) -> Vector a`, and when you try to apply it to `(id .) :: (x -> y) -> (x -> y)` you end up needing to instantiate `x = forall s. ST s (MVector s a)`, which explodes. It's not that there's anything really *wrong* with the required instantiation; it's just that GHC cannot deal with it. There used to be an extension, `ImpredicativePolymorphism`, that tried to give limited support, but as of GHC 8 it's completely broken and deprecated. The reason `($)` still works is because it's actually hardwired into GHC so that it can avoid the issue, which is why if you tried to define

```
f $$ x = f x
```

and used it instead of `($)` here it'd fail similarly to `(id .)`.